# Force an illegal typecast in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

There's a failure case in my Objective-C app where an (NSDate *) points to a CFString and crashes when a date method is called.

I'm writing a unit test in Swift to simulate this case but it seems impossible because of Swift's type safety. I've written a little Objective-C factory class to create the messed up object for now but I was wondering if anyone knows a way to force an illegal typecast in Swift. Like a version of this that doesn't fail at runtime:

```
obj.date = NSString() as! NSDate
```

Answer (score 5):

`as!` will always do a runtime check, and `unsafeDowncast()` will do a runtime check in debug builds (but not release builds).

To always skip the runtime check, use `unsafeBitCast()`:

```
let myString : NSString = "Hello"
let myDate : NSDate = unsafeBitCast(myString, NSDate.self)

NSLog("%@", myDate) // "Hello"
```

Comment: I get this error: `fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`

Comment: @rgbrgb Make sure you're casting between two reference types (e.g., NSString and NSDate).  It won't work with a Swift value type like `String` or `Array`

Comment: @Darren can you elaborate why this doesn't work with collection types?  What if I want to `unsafeBitCast` an `[Int]` to `[CustomStringConvertible]` or something like that?  What are my options without using something like `map`?

Comment: @JAL `unsafeBitCast` merely skips the compile-time and run-time checks; it doesn't do any actual conversion.  It "works" for types of the same size (e.g. `Int32` and `Float`) as well as arrays of types that have the same size (e.g., [Int32] and [Float]).  It doesn't work for protocols like CustomStringConvertible because (I believe) there is additional type information included in a `CustomStringConvertible` variable that's not included in an `Int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Cast up to AnyObject and now you can cast down to any class you like.

```
let s = "howdy"
let id = s as AnyObject
let crash = id as! NSDate
```

Comment: There is a reason I called that variable `id`!

Comment: I get a runtime error: `Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x109d3e9d0) to 'NSDate' (0x1095026f0).`

Comment: Because it's _not_ an NSDate. I mean, look, you knew this wasn't going to magically _turn_ a string into a date. But that wasn't what you asked. You asked how to make the cast _legal_, i.e. to get it past the _compiler_. And I gave you that. Obviously the cast isn't actually going to _change_ anything. There's a reason why this cast is illegal!

Comment: The question is about writing a test case. The code in question is supposed to simulate an error case in my code (NSDate * getting set to a CFString). I didn't find a way to do what I'm looking for in Swift so I'm still using an Obj-C factory class which does the trick -- I was just hoping to be able to keep my whole test suite in Swift. If you find a solution, please post it. Otherwise, thanks anyway for thinking about it with me.